# How to remove blurriness around pie chart when using custom colors?

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart, donut-chart

I'm using MPAndroidchart pie chart and used my own colors for charts. Now the problem is the pie chart is blurred. Its edges are in blur. I want to remove the blur and make it sharp edges.How to do it?

I don't have 10 reputations to post image.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1umms-1LZj0XuuKuDpOWZqcpRCOn6rh-X
[image]

Here is the code for chart displaying.

```
private void showChart(BudgetResponse.Budgets[] items) {
        chart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        chart.setUsePercentValues(true);
        chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        chart.setExtraOffsets(5, 10, 5, 5);

        chart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.95f);

        //chart.setCenterTextTypeface(tfLight);
        //chart.setCenterText(generateCenterSpannableText());


        chart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
        chart.setHoleColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        chart.setTransparentCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
        chart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(110);

        chart.setHoleRadius(58f);
        chart.setTransparentCircleRadius(61f);

        chart.setDrawCenterText(true);
        SimpleSpanBuilder sb=new SimpleSpanBuilder();
        sb.append("Total budget",new RelativeSizeSpan(1.0f));
        float budget=0;
        try{
            for (int i=0;i<items.length;i++){
                budget+=Float.parseFloat(items[i].getCurrentAmount());
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sb.append("\n"+budget,new RelativeSizeSpan(2.0f),
                new ForegroundColorSpan(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));

        chart.setCenterText(sb.build());
        chart.setCenterTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.titleColor));
        chart.setCenterTextSizePixels(12f);

        chart.setRotationAngle(0);
        // enable rotation of the chart by touch
        chart.setRotationEnabled(false);
        chart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true);

        chart.animateY(1400, Easing.EaseInOutQuad);

        chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

        ArrayList<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<Integer> pieColors=new ArrayList<>();

        for (BudgetResponse.Budgets budgets:items){
            entries.add(new PieEntry(Float.parseFloat(budgets.getCurrentAmount()), budgets.getCategoryGroupName()));
            if(budgets.getCategoryGroupName().contains("Bills")){
                pieColors.add(getAppColor(R.color.lightViolet));
            }else if(budgets.getCategoryGroupName().contains("Entertainment")){
                pieColors.add(getAppColor(R.color.lightPink));
            }else if(budgets.getCategoryGroupName().contains("Food")){
                pieColors.add(getAppColor(R.color.lightBlue));
            }else if(budgets.getCategoryGroupName().contains("Auto")){
                pieColors.add(getAppColor(R.color.darkViolet));
            }else if(budgets.getCategoryGroupName().contains("Shopping")){
                pieColors.add(getAppColor(R.color.lightOrangeVariant));
            }else if(budgets.getCategoryGroupName().contains("Transfers")){
                pieColors.add(getAppColor(R.color.lightGreenVariant));
            }
        }
        // add a lot of colors

        ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>(pieColors);

        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, "Budget Spends");

        dataSet.setDrawIcons(false);

        dataSet.setSliceSpace(3f);
        dataSet.setIconsOffset(new MPPointF(0, 40));
        dataSet.setSelectionShift(1f);


        colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());

        dataSet.setColors(colors);
        //dataSet.setSelectionShift(0f);

        PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
        data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter(chart));
        data.setValueTextSize(11f);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        //data.setValueTypeface(tfLight);
        chart.setData(data);

        //to remove labels over pie chart
        chart.setDrawEntryLabels(false);
        //to remove percentage over pie chart
        chart.setUsePercentValues(false);
        //chart.setDrawCenterText(false);

        // undo all highlights
        chart.highlightValues(null);

        MyMarkerView mv = new MyMarkerView(activity, R.layout.custom_marker_view);
        mv.setChartView(chart); // For bounds control
        chart.setMarker(mv); //

        chart.invalidate();

    }
```

I want to remove blurriness around chart.

[image: Reason in detail]
In activity the donut chat looks great. But in viewpager it looks blur.